# How to use 'convert' and 'xargs' together?

Tags: linux, bash, image-manipulation

I need to convert a bunch of `.rgb` files into `.png`s (each file should retain its original name).

I want to find out how to convert the first file and then wrap the command in a 'for' loop.

This is what i have so far:

```
find . -name "*.rgb" | sort | sed -n \1\p | xargs convert zzzzz.png
```

But this doens't work.

How can I make the `convert` command to recognize the second argument `zzzzz.png`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to convert all files in the dir-tree I would run:

```
find . -name '*.rgb' | parallel convert {} {.}.png
```

This will in parallel run:

```
convert ./foo.rgb ./foo.png
convert ./bar/quux.rgb ./bar/quux.png
```

Here I use GNU Parallel to make use of all your CPU's. Depending on your system you can install it as a package, otherwise it is here [gnu.org/software/parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). In Debian it is:

```
apt-get install parallel
```

Edit:
Here is a solution without `GNU Parallel`:

```
find . -name '*.rgb' -exec sh -c 'convert "$0" "${0%.*}.png"' {} \;
```

and a not so nice solution using `while..read`:

```
find . -name '*.rgb' | while read FILE; do convert "${FILE}" "${FILE%rgb}png" ; done
```

Comment: I couldn't get the parallel version to work under OSX - it just did nothing (a problem with parallel itself I think). Thanks for posting a working find..exec alternative, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

To convert (in my case resize) all the images in a single directory I use

```
ls *.jpg | xargs -I {} convert {} -resize 1024x768 resized/{}
```

Please note how the curly braces placeholder for the filename can be used twice. You could also use it add a prefix to the target file name.

For recursive search:

```
find -name '*.jpg' | xargs -I {} convert {} -resize 1024x768 resized/{}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer:

```
for i in 'seq 1 $numOfRGBfiles'; do
#Insert code here that finds the file
#name of each rgb file and stores it 
#in $filename.

'find . -name "*.rgb" | sort | sed -n 
\$i\p |  xargs -I {} convert {} 
\$filename.png'
done
```

Comment: In my system, convert can take two arguments(e.g. convert inputImage.rgb outputImage.png )

Comment: In my code, covert is taking just one input file for every for loop iteration.

Comment: It is not good practice to do `seq 1 $numOfRGBfiles`. It is better to do `for all`. The problem is that a file can disappear while the loop is running, or a new can occur.